# Calculating the hyperbolic distance between two points on a geodesic in $\mathbb{H}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

[[image: Geodesics in <span class=]$\mathbb{H}^2$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka7ib.png)

I've been trying to self-study differential geometry lately, but I'm struggling with some of the ideas of hyperbolic space. I came across a problem here, to where the points P and Q are $(1,1)$ and $(2, \sqrt{2})$ respectively, and I'm to find the hyperbolic distance between them by the following steps:

i.) I should find the coordinates of the endpoints of the purple geodesic $\gamma$ on which the points P and Q lie

ii.) It's given that when we invert the green semi-circle C, whose center is at the right-hand endpoint of $\gamma$ and whose radius is twice that of $\gamma$, we get the vertical blue line with which the points P' and Q' reside. I should then calculate the coordinates of the images P' of P and Q' of Q on the line using similar triangles, and lastly

iii.) Calculate the exact hyperbolic distance between P' and Q', and deduce the hyperbolic distance between P and Q justly.

I'm familiar with the workings of Mobius transformations and conformal mappings in $\mathbb{C}$, but here I'm not sure how to envision things, and am not seeing a clear way to begin.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to look at Section 2 of Chapter 3 of my differential geometry text, freely available at the link in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you get stuck?

Step i) is finding the semicircle whose endpoints are on the $x$-axis that contains the points $P$ and $Q$. This is basically an exercise in basic algebra. It suffices to find the center of the full circle, which is the point on the $x$-axis whose distances to $P$ and to $Q$ are equal and therefore equal to the radius.

To do Step ii), recall or figure how the distance from a point inside the large semicircle to the semicircle is related to the distance from the inverted point to the semicircle. You could also try to find the formula for the Mobius transformation corresponding to the inversion. But if you take this approach, I suggest first sliding everything horizontally so that the center of the larger semicircle is at the origin.

Step iii) uses the fact that the vertical line is a geodesic and the formula for the hyperbolic metric.